# How to avoid a particular dependency cycle on file definitions in puppet

Tags: puppet

I have the following puppet config section:

```
class a {
    file { "/etc/nrpe.d/nrpe_local.cfg":
        source => "puppet:///modules/blah/bar.cfg",
     }
}

class b{
    require a
    file { 'etc':
        path => '/etc/',
        ensure => 'present',
        source => 'puppet:///modules/blah/etc',
        ignore => "nrpe.d",
        recurse => true,
    }
}
```

Now this is causing a dependency cycle, but I thought that adding nrpe.d in the ignore list in the second file definition should take care of it. How can I tell puppet that the second file definition should not include nrpe.d as a dependency?
For other reasons I am unable to load b before a (hence the require).

Comment: I also tried "nrpe.d/*", "nrpe.d/nrpe_local.cfg" and adding /etc in front

Comment: Don't `require a`. Your manifest is the textbook reason why this practice should be avoided. Why not just `include a`?